# Why am I getting errors while executing argparse in python

Tags: python

I am not able to parse the argument in python for detecting eyeblink with OpenCv, python, and dlib.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
        help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="",
    help="path to input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True)

_StoreAction(option_strings=['-p', '--shape-predictor'], 
dest='shape_predictor', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, 
choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-v', '--video'], dest='video', nargs=None, const=None, default='', type=<class 'str'>, choices=None, help=None, 
metavar=None)

args = vars(ap.parse_args())

usage: [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-v VIDEO]
error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor
```

Comment: redo the code, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
usage: [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-v VIDEO]
error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor
```

Is the output of your command line ?

I'm not sure, but you're a possibly forgetting to set the -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR flag, which seem to be a mandatory option. Your argparser is returning an error because he haven't correct arguments

Comment: Thank you for your response. But since I am new in this field I would thankful if you could share me the syntax. Thanx in advance.